# Pass a variable (id) from one function to another function

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my php script so basiclly I pull database values into a $result and then $row and use $row['blabla'] inside if and so on. The problem is I cant seem to send that specific ID or that database row instead of just the one row being increased by X all of the rows column values are increased by X

This is the first function.

```
function listEvents($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM basicevents";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if($row['EventCurrFunds'] < $row['EventMaxFunds']) {
                echo "<div class='container border border-info'>
                <div class='row pb-3 text-center'>
                  <div class='col-md p-3 border border-info'>" . $row['EventName'] . "</div>
                  <div class='vol-md p-3 border border-info'>" . $row['EventDate'] . "</div>
                </div>
                <div class='row pb-3 text-center'>
                  <div class='col-md p-3 border border-info'>
                  Capacity = " . $row['EventCapacity'] . "
                  </div>
                  <div class='col-md p-3 border border-info'>
                  " . $row['EventCurrFunds'] . "/" . $row['EventMaxFunds'] . "
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md p-3 border border-info'>
                  <form class='border border-info' action='" . addFunds($conn, $row['EventID']) . "'  method='POST'>
                  <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='funds'>Enter funds</label>
                    <input type='number' class='form-control w-50' placeholder='Enter required funding' name='funds'>
                  </div>
                  <button type='submit' name='fundsSubmit' class='btn btn-info p-2 w-25'>Add funds</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div><br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Increasing the EventCurrFunds is done via calling the addFunds() after inputing via $_POST

```
function addFunds($conn, $id) {
    if(isset($_POST['fundsSubmit'])) {
        $aux = $_POST['funds'];
        $sql = "UPDATE basicevents SET EventCurrFunds = EventCurrFunds + '$aux' WHERE EventID = '$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}
```

I tried giving the ID of that specific while itteration however id doesnt work. All column values of basicevents EventCurrFunds are increased instead of just the one whose ID I want to give to the addFunds Function.

Comment: I've not tested your code, but it looks to me like `addFunds` will execute for _every single row_ in your result set if `$_POST['fundsSubmit']` evaluates to true.  I notice that you have the form `action` set to the result of that function - is that what you want to do?  The `action` is used by the web client to determine where to send the form result when the user submits the form.

Comment: can we see a few rows of the database in a 'expected result; actual result' format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line `<form class='border border-info' action='" . addFunds($conn, $row['EventID']) . "'  method='POST'>` is wrong

you may use this :
`<form class='border border-info' action='./?id=" . $row['EventID'] . "'  method='POST'>`

so you can get the id from `$_GET['id']`

**add** 
If you want all to be in `$_POST` you can do this :

```
<form class='border border-info' action=''  method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='eventid' value='". $row['EventID'] .">
```

so you can get the id from `$_POST['eventid']`

Comment: Thank you, so I could create a global array of ID values and send that into the function instead of the session key which is set again during each while itteration?

Comment: While this may work it is generally not a good idea to use global variables like that if at all possible. It makes maintaining your code difficult and may cause confusion when trying to debug problems.

Comment: oh .. i reviewed your code .. this line `<form class='border border-info' action='" . addFunds($conn, $row['EventID']) . "'  method='POST'>` is wrong ! i'll edit my answer

Comment: @AlaaMorad Do you mean $_POST? Because the method is still post and my addfunds is not called anywhere. I am kinda lost, sry I dont have much experience.

Comment: @JJ_Badoo No because `id` is in the action/url .. this is a POST&GET method

Comment: @AlaaMorad I figured out the get and post stuff thanks a lot, that part was always blurry. Regarding `addFunds($conn)` , Should I call that function at the end of the while loop or somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know the whole program or the concept your are using .. but since the `addFunds` is used when the user click on submit button so it must be outside the `while` .. actually it must be outside the `listEvents` function . but consider calling `addFunds` before calling `listEvents` so the `listEvents` will output an updated list if events